# Returning a specific View for a Telerik grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, razor

I have a model which contains a customer record and can have multiple projects pertaining to that customer.

```
Html.Telerik().Grid<YeagerTechModel.Customer>
```

I have two actions in the Controller. One that returns just the Customer records and the other one contains the Customer record associated with its Projects. The below syntax is for binding the data to the View.

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customerList = db.GetCustomers();
return View(new GridModel<Customer> { Data = customerList });
```

I was planning to set up two separate views. One for each of the scenarios described above. However, since the above syntax includes data for possible projects, do I need to make one View and hide the Projects grid (hierarchial) or can I have two separate views (one with just the Customers and another hierarchialone for the Customer and its associated Projects)?

According to the syntax that is used above, it seems that I can only use the one hierarchial view.

Comment: Can you not just pass the view name you want to show? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it would be just like this:

```
    return View("**Viewname**", new GridModel<Customer> 
    { 
Data = customerList }
    );
```